# Problem communicating with UART1 with Python on Beaglebone Black

Tags: uart, beaglebone-black, python

I am having issues communicatong to UART1 of my Beaglebone Black with python

My code on Python3 is as follows:

import Adafruit_BBIO.ADC as ADC

import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO

from time import sleep

import Adafruit_BBIO.UART as UART

import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port = "/dev/ttyO1", baudrate=9600)

print("Open")

ser.write(("Hello").encode)

print("message sent")

ser.read()

However, the beaglebone is sending me back:

Open

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "GPIO60.py", line 14, in
ser.write(("Hello").encode)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 518, in write
d = to_bytes(data)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 66, in to_bytes
return (bytes(bytearray(seq)))

TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

I have searched solutions for this type of error but have found nothing.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: You mean: /dev/tty<zero>1 "/dev/tty01"?  Also as a general rule of thumb, unless you know what is going on, I avoid serial ports 1-4, as they are often used on the motherboard for inter-device communication.

Comment: No /dev/ttyO1 which is also /dev/ttyS1. I can communicate using the minicom but I want to do so with python. I am doing a project, but using this just to test if it works

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a python syntax error which belongs on Stackoverflow not EESE

Answer (score 1):

Your error message is a pure python programming problem, which means the question doesn't really belong on EESE but rather Stackoverflow, however for sake of efficiency an answer here will migrate with the question.

```
ser.write(("Hello").encode)
```

This is invalid python.  There is no such thing as `.encode` rather you need the *method* `.encode()` if you want the default encoding, or to pass a specific encoding as an argument if you want some other.

```
ser.write(("Hello").encode()) #UTF-8 which is probably not what you want
```

or mabye

```
ser.write(("Hello").encode('iso-8859-1')) #a legacy friendly encoding
```

Also you probably don't want to both import the Adafruit UART code *and* use pyserial on the Linux device.  For a given UART, you'll need to be consistent in how you work with it.

Comment: ok sorry for disturbing, i am new here so i don't know how it works, thanks anyway